# XSL-FO how to propagate page numbering from template to another

Tags: templates, layout, printing, xsl-fo, page-numbering

It is my first experience in XSL-FO printing.

There are 2 templates each has its own layout.xsl

It is needed to edit the page numbering of second template to be successor to the first one.

Example

template one has 4 pages, then template two should start by page no. 5 not 1!

I have an ideas but still doesn't work; is to create a 3rd template that call these 2 templates

```
<xsl:template>
        <xsl:call-template name="templateOne" />
        <!-- <xsl:block break-after="page"/> -->
        <xsl:call-template name="templateTwo" />
        <!-- <xsl:block break-after="page"/> -->
</xsl:template>
```

Layout of templateOne:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>       
            <xsl:call-template name="LayoutMasterSet"/>
            <xsl:variable name="TheVeryLastPage" select="."/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$titel='Anwendungsprotokoll'">
                    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="landscape" initial-page-number="1" format="1">
                        <!-- Kopfzeile -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="StandardKopfzeile">
                            <xsl:with-param name="TheVeryLastPage"><xsl:value-of select="$TheVeryLastPage"/></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <!-- Fusszeile -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="StandardFusszeile">
                            <xsl:with-param name="TheVeryLastPage"><xsl:value-of select="$TheVeryLastPage"/></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                            <fo:block font-size="8pt" line-height="10pt">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:block id="{generate-id($TheVeryLastPage)}"/>
                        </fo:flow>
                    </fo:page-sequence>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="default-pages" initial-page-number="1" format="1">
                        <!-- Kopfzeile -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="StandardKopfzeile">
                            <xsl:with-param name="TheVeryLastPage"><xsl:value-of select="$TheVeryLastPage"/></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <!-- Fusszeile -->
                        <xsl:call-template name="StandardFusszeile">
                            <xsl:with-param name="TheVeryLastPage"><xsl:value-of select="$TheVeryLastPage"/></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                            <fo:block font-size="8pt" line-height="10pt">
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
                            </fo:block>
                            <fo:block id="{generate-id($TheVeryLastPage)}"/>
                        </fo:flow>
                    </fo:page-sequence>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
```

Layout of templateTwo:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xsl:use-attribute-sets="font.arial.8.normal.black">
            <xsl:call-template name="LayoutMasterSet"/>
            <xsl:variable name="TheVeryLastPage" select="."/>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="default-pages" initial-page-number="1" format="1">
                <xsl:call-template name="StandardHeader"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="GeneralFooter">
                    <xsl:with-param name="TheVeryLastPage">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$TheVeryLastPage"/>
                    </xsl:with-param>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Layout Master Set+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ -->
    <xsl:template name="LayoutMasterSet">
        <fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="any-page" page-height="297mm" page-width="210mm" margin-top="1.5cm" margin-bottom="1.5cm" margin-left="1.5cm" margin-right="1.5cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="2cm" margin-bottom="2cm" column-count="{$columns}"/>
                <fo:region-before extent="2cm" region-name="region-before"/>
                <fo:region-after extent="2cm" region-name="region-after"/>
            </fo:simple-page-master>
            <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="default-pages">
                <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="any" master-reference="any-page"/>
                </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            </fo:page-sequence-master>
        </fo:layout-master-set>
    </xsl:template>
```

This idea doesn't work, it gives me:

```
saving .xsl. <anonymous development build> javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format}table" is not a valid child of "fo:page-sequence"!

ERROR |17:33:05,752|DefaultExceptionHandler.logException:75 (WorkerThread 17:31:48)[-1] TRANSFORMATION_ERROR [] <anonymous development build>
de.vodafone.core.exception.BadProcessingException: [-1] TRANSFORMATION_ERROR []
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.shared.print.fop.FopPrintService.addToPageable(FopPrintService.java:165)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.shared.print.fop.FopPrintService.print(FopPrintService.java:78)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.shared.print.fop.PrintServiceDelegator.print(PrintServiceDelegator.java:53)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.shared.print.activity.AbstractPrintAgent.execute(AbstractPrintAgent.java:213)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.shared.activity.ActivityManager.execute(ActivityManager.java:78)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.plugin.order.manager.common.presentation.AbstractOrderFacade.executeActivities(AbstractOrderFacade.java:210)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.plugin.order.manager.common.presentation.SingleCustomerOrderFacade.handleAfterSave(SingleCustomerOrderFacade.java:101)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.plugin.fixednet.activation.mvc.FNActivationFacade.handleAfterSave(FNActivationFacade.java:370)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.plugin.order.manager.common.presentation.AbstractOrderFacade.save(AbstractOrderFacade.java:335)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.plugin.order.manager.common.presentation.AbstractOrderFacade.save(AbstractOrderFacade.java:298)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.plugin.order.manager.common.presentation.AbstractOrderFacade.send(AbstractOrderFacade.java:117)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.plugin.order.manager.common.presentation.AbstractOrderController.send(AbstractOrderController.java:943)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.plugin.order.manager.common.presentation.AbstractOrderController.onSend(AbstractOrderController.java:861)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.plugin.order.manager.common.presentation.AbstractOrderController$10.doExecuteCommand(AbstractOrderController.java:1258)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.framework.ui.action.AbstractWidgetActionUIJob.execute(AbstractWidgetActionUIJob.java:45)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.framework.ui.action.RunnableBuilder$CommandRunnable.run(RunnableBuilder.java:196)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.client.framework.ui.action.AbstractUIJob.run(AbstractUIJob.java:50)
    at EDU.oswego.cs.dl.util.concurrent.QueuedExecutor$RunLoop.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format}table" is not a valid child of "fo:page-sequence"! (Siehe Position 17:276)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:469)
    at de.vodafone.app.epos.shared.print.fop.FopPrintService.addToPageable(FopPrintService.java:156)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.fop.fo.ValidationException: "{http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format}table" is not a valid child of "fo:page-sequence"! (Siehe Position 17:276)
    at org.apache.fop.events.ValidationExceptionFactory.createException(ValidationExceptionFactory.java:38)
    at org.apache.fop.events.EventExceptionManager.throwException(EventExceptionManager.java:54)
    at org.apache.fop.events.DefaultEventBroadcaster$1.invoke(DefaultEventBroadcaster.java:175)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.invalidChild(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(FONode.java:534)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FONode.invalidChildError(FONode.java:517)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.pagination.PageSequence.validateChildNode(PageSequence.java:147)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder$MainFOHandler.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:267)
    at org.apache.fop.fo.FOTreeBuilder.startElement(FOTreeBuilder.java:171)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.startElement(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:1020)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:452)
    ... 19 more
```

Cause I am not the one that write these huge templates, I couldn't find the bad location of fo:table inside fo:page-sequence

Moreover, the page number is not propagated. I think to define a param that initially by 1 and setted by the last page of templateOne to be incremented by 1 and initialized the first page of Template 2 just after fixing the previous formation exception.

Your help is really appricated 
Thanks a lot
Mariam

Comment: Are you trying to create one PDF document or two documents?

Comment: one document to print. which include 2 template wach has its own layout.xsl, I got the previous error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the `fo:table` problem, you need an `fo:flow` inside your `fo:page-sequence` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_page-sequence). templateOne has it (but the properties on the `fo:block` inside the `fo:flow` could be put on the `fo:flow` and the `fo:block` could be omitted). templateTwo does not have an `fo:flow` inside its `fo:page-sequence`.

Your other problem is that both templates create an `fo:root`. `fo:root` is, as the name implies, the root of the FO document. Since the FO document that you are generating is also an XML document, the document can only have one 'document' element, i.e., one `fo:root`.

Please see this diagram from Section 6.4.1.6, Pagination Tree Structure, of the XSL 1.1 Recommendation (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e7181)

[image: Pagination tree structure diagram from https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e7181]

However, the diagram fails to show that `fo:root` may contain multiple `fo:page-sequence` (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_root).

To get templateOne and templateTwo to work together, you should generate one `fo:root` and one `fo:layout-master-set` and have templateOne and templateTwo generate content starting at the `fo:page-sequence` level.  Something like:

```
fo:root
  fo:layout-master-set
  fo:page-sequence (generated by templateOne)
  fo:page-sequence (generated by templateTwo)
```

If you do all that, then you will have solved the question in the title. The default value for the `initial-page-number` property (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#initial-page-number) on each `fo:page-sequence` will make the second `fo:page-sequence` start with the page number after the last page number of the previous `fo:page-sequence`.

Another lurking problem is that both templateOne and templateTwo include:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/*"/>
```

If you are processing one source document, then you are going to get two copies of your content. We can't help you with that unless we know more about the structure of the XML that you are trying to process.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of the information, concerning "make the second fo:page-sequence start with the page number after the last page number of the previous fo:page-sequence." page number of templateOne is unkown and dynamicly generated. so the page number of templateTwo should stared by templateOne.page number+1. how can I fulfill this requirement.

Comment: The formatter will do it for you.  The formatter makes the pages, so it obviously knows the page number of the last page that it created. The default behaviour is to just continue the page numbering from the previous `fo:page-sequence`.  It would drive us all crazy if it didn't work that way.

Comment: so the fo:page-sequence in TempolateTwo/layout could be  <fo:page-sequence master-reference="default-pages" initial-page-number="1" format="1"> or I should change the value of initial-page-number?

Comment: If you remove `initial-page-number`, it will have its initial value of `auto`, which is the value that you want. You can remove `format="1"` since the initial value of `format` is `1`.